# Heatmap for repeated data

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am able to generate a heatmap with some financial time series data, but I don't think it shows what I want it to show (the average price movement for each hour of each day)

[image]

When I check the average price movements for a certain hour, it is different to that indicated on the chart.

The code I've used is below:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time, y=Weekday, fill = Change)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1) + 
  scale_x_time(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name="Price change", option = "plasma") + 
  theme_bw(base_family="Helvetica") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

Change is hourly price change for several years of data. Time is the hour (00:00, 01:00) and weekday is the day of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.) They are both factors, maybe I need to make them time variables to get average price change for each square in the diagram?

Does anyone know how I can get the average price movement for each hour of the day as I dont want just any change in price to be placed into the heatmap.

Snippet of the data

```
Date    Time    Change  Weekday
09/03/2016  16:00   1.980786372 Wednesday
09/03/2016  17:00   0.000000000 Wednesday
09/03/2016  18:00   0.000000000 Wednesday
09/03/2016  20:00   -4.778919160    Wednesday
09/03/2016  21:00   -2.920425114    Wednesday
10/03/2016  16:00   6.123554913 Thursday
10/03/2016  17:00   0.851063830 Thursday
11/03/2016  10:00   0.000000000 Friday
11/03/2016  17:00   0.000000000 Friday
11/03/2016  18:00   0.000000000 Friday
11/03/2016  21:00   0.843881857 Friday
11/03/2016  22:00   0.000000000 Friday
11/03/2016  23:00   0.000000000 Friday
12/03/2016  02:00   1.924686192 Saturday
12/03/2016  03:00   4.448267388 Saturday
12/03/2016  04:00   -1.233616037    Saturday
12/03/2016  07:00   0.000000000 Saturday
12/03/2016  09:00   -5.263157895    Saturday
12/03/2016  12:00   -0.142322097    Saturday
12/03/2016  18:00   0.000000000 Saturday
13/03/2016  00:00   2.973977695 Sunday
13/03/2016  01:00   0.722021661 Sunday
13/03/2016  10:00   0.000000000 Sunday
13/03/2016  12:00   0.000000000 Sunday
13/03/2016  15:00   0.000000000 Sunday
13/03/2016  19:00   0.000000000 Sunday
13/03/2016  20:00   1.010101010 Sunday
13/03/2016  21:00   0.000000000 Sunday
13/03/2016  23:00   -2.587601078    Sunday
14/03/2016  00:00   -17.094487647   Monday
14/03/2016  01:00   1.209992194 Monday
14/03/2016  02:00   0.000000000 Monday
14/03/2016  09:00   -1.132075472    Monday
14/03/2016  10:00   -0.763358779    Monday
14/03/2016  11:00   -0.222222222    Monday
14/03/2016  12:00   4.797047970 Monday
14/03/2016  13:00   -1.761403509    Monday
14/03/2016  14:00   -2.857142857    Monday
14/03/2016  15:00   1.098739031 Monday
14/03/2016  16:00   -0.277008310    Monday
14/03/2016  17:00   0.870827286 Monday
14/03/2016  18:00   6.057553957 Monday
14/03/2016  19:00   -7.430004745    Monday
14/03/2016  20:00   1.054183561 Monday
14/03/2016  21:00   -2.976364167    Monday
14/03/2016  22:00   -3.306650707    Monday
14/03/2016  23:00   -4.149922720    Monday
15/03/2016  00:00   1.964415103 Tuesday
15/03/2016  01:00   0.493198632 Tuesday
15/03/2016  02:00   -1.473007913    Tuesday
15/03/2016  03:00   -3.752988048    Tuesday
15/03/2016  04:00   4.662525880 Tuesday
15/03/2016  05:00   -2.856238626    Tuesday
15/03/2016  06:00   1.950553861 Tuesday
15/03/2016  07:00   0.466698307 Tuesday
15/03/2016  08:00   1.648222275 Tuesday
15/03/2016  09:00   -0.702648444    Tuesday
15/03/2016  10:00   0.023116043 Tuesday
15/03/2016  11:00   0.145716696 Tuesday
15/03/2016  12:00   -1.045671229    Tuesday
15/03/2016  13:00   -0.656117329    Tuesday
15/03/2016  14:00   -5.497076023    Tuesday
15/03/2016  15:00   1.952420016 Tuesday
15/03/2016  16:00   -1.252408478    Tuesday
15/03/2016  17:00   0.984665052 Tuesday
15/03/2016  18:00   3.764386189 Tuesday
15/03/2016  19:00   -0.330769231    Tuesday
15/03/2016  20:00   -0.309310238    Tuesday
15/03/2016  21:00   -0.445069103    Tuesday
15/03/2016  22:00   -1.046511628    Tuesday
15/03/2016  23:00   0.699515720 Tuesday
16/03/2016  00:00   3.053435115 Wednesday
16/03/2016  01:00   0.506253722 Wednesday
16/03/2016  02:00   -0.985185185    Wednesday
16/03/2016  03:00   -1.847834219    Wednesday
16/03/2016  04:00   0.495426829 Wednesday
16/03/2016  05:00   0.792682927 Wednesday
16/03/2016  06:00   1.427169070 Wednesday
16/03/2016  07:00   -1.421064318    Wednesday
16/03/2016  08:00   -0.534196073    Wednesday
16/03/2016  09:00   2.426487263 Wednesday
16/03/2016  10:00   1.609434102 Wednesday
16/03/2016  11:00   -0.789473684    Wednesday
16/03/2016  12:00   0.877840071 Wednesday
16/03/2016  13:00   -2.807195706    Wednesday
16/03/2016  14:00   -0.514963803    Wednesday
16/03/2016  15:00   -1.849779966    Wednesday
16/03/2016  16:00   -2.112622540    Wednesday
16/03/2016  17:00   -0.679641643    Wednesday
16/03/2016  18:00   1.213573471 Wednesday
16/03/2016  19:00   0.000000000 Wednesday
16/03/2016  20:00   -1.509146341    Wednesday
16/03/2016  21:00   1.137066832 Wednesday
16/03/2016  22:00   -2.185541800    Wednesday
16/03/2016  23:00   -1.968750000    Wednesday
17/03/2016  00:00   -0.557857826    Thursday
17/03/2016  01:00   -1.062300319    Thursday
17/03/2016  02:00   0.347138129 Thursday
17/03/2016  03:00   0.602022797 Thursday
17/03/2016  04:00   0.393859015 Thursday
17/03/2016  05:00   0.240192154 Thursday
17/03/2016  06:00   0.731570062 Thursday
17/03/2016  07:00   -4.329073482    Thursday
17/03/2016  08:00   -5.912426816    Thursday
17/03/2016  09:00   2.107081174 Thursday
17/03/2016  10:00   0.684468481 Thursday
17/03/2016  11:00   -8.531163493    Thursday
17/03/2016  12:00   2.435005492 Thursday
17/03/2016  13:00   -3.139013453    Thursday
17/03/2016  14:00   1.421140628 Thursday
17/03/2016  15:00   2.541508209 Thursday
17/03/2016  16:00   -4.054054054    Thursday
17/03/2016  17:00   0.469483568 Thursday
17/03/2016  18:00   0.046433878 Thursday
17/03/2016  19:00   3.880184332 Thursday
17/03/2016  20:00   0.246218783 Thursday
17/03/2016  21:00   -1.745200698    Thursday
17/03/2016  22:00   1.030927835 Thursday
17/03/2016  23:00   -1.276785714    Thursday
18/03/2016  00:00   0.361010830 Friday
18/03/2016  01:00   -2.666064166    Friday
18/03/2016  02:00   0.649953575 Friday
18/03/2016  03:00   1.390176089 Friday
18/03/2016  04:00   0.548446069 Friday
18/03/2016  05:00   0.569538857 Friday
18/03/2016  06:00   -3.467889908    Friday
18/03/2016  07:00   -1.692015209    Friday
18/03/2016  08:00   -0.988180585    Friday
18/03/2016  09:00   -5.900195695    Friday
18/03/2016  10:00   1.409457665 Friday
18/03/2016  11:00   -13.000873193   Friday
18/03/2016  12:00   -4.120443740    Friday
18/03/2016  13:00   7.302062736 Friday
18/03/2016  14:00   9.649122807 Friday
18/03/2016  15:00   2.581039021 Friday
18/03/2016  16:00   -2.198124267    Friday
18/03/2016  17:00   -2.137648587    Friday
18/03/2016  18:00   -0.050236110    Friday
18/03/2016  19:00   1.920744036 Friday
18/03/2016  20:00   1.344032096 Friday
18/03/2016  21:00   -0.215876754    Friday
18/03/2016  22:00   6.667989680 Friday
18/03/2016  23:00   2.042711235 Friday
19/03/2016  00:00   -4.858962693    Saturday
19/03/2016  01:00   -0.861008610    Saturday
19/03/2016  02:00   -0.907787864    Saturday
19/03/2016  03:00   2.030947776 Saturday
19/03/2016  04:00   -0.511848341    Saturday
19/03/2016  05:00   -5.607566837    Saturday
19/03/2016  06:00   2.516676774 Saturday
19/03/2016  07:00   0.167570232 Saturday
19/03/2016  08:00   6.335900185 Saturday
19/03/2016  09:00   -0.632505271    Saturday
19/03/2016  10:00   -2.608213097    Saturday
19/03/2016  11:00   1.277528840 Saturday
19/03/2016  12:00   2.742999140 Saturday
19/03/2016  13:00   -0.270522388    Saturday
19/03/2016  14:00   -0.981481481    Saturday
19/03/2016  15:00   2.432179607 Saturday
19/03/2016  16:00   0.182648402 Saturday
19/03/2016  17:00   -1.276207840    Saturday
19/03/2016  18:00   -2.123730379    Saturday
19/03/2016  19:00   -3.161350844    Saturday
19/03/2016  20:00   0.862068966 Saturday
19/03/2016  21:00   -3.133903134    Saturday
19/03/2016  22:00   -0.039215686    Saturday
19/03/2016  23:00   2.920276453 Saturday
20/03/2016  00:00   -1.312682973    Sunday
20/03/2016  01:00   0.293282876 Sunday
20/03/2016  02:00   -2.159624413    Sunday
20/03/2016  03:00   2.097565669 Sunday
20/03/2016  04:00   -0.459705413    Sunday
20/03/2016  05:00   -0.961813161    Sunday
20/03/2016  06:00   0.508149569 Sunday
20/03/2016  07:00   -1.104707012    Sunday
20/03/2016  08:00   0.000000000 Sunday
20/03/2016  09:00   0.009765625 Sunday
20/03/2016  10:00   0.726532985 Sunday
20/03/2016  11:00   0.260869565 Sunday
20/03/2016  12:00   0.019426906 Sunday
20/03/2016  13:00   -2.682997959    Sunday
20/03/2016  14:00   -1.027667984    Sunday
20/03/2016  15:00   0.519117500 Sunday
20/03/2016  16:00   -1.900099900    Sunday
20/03/2016  17:00   1.530612245 Sunday
20/03/2016  18:00   -3.028479743    Sunday
20/03/2016  19:00   1.715597936 Sunday
20/03/2016  20:00   1.208459215 Sunday
20/03/2016  21:00   0.591133005 Sunday
20/03/2016  22:00   -2.233009709    Sunday
20/03/2016  23:00   1.302288871 Sunday
21/03/2016  00:00   -0.743712692    Monday
21/03/2016  01:00   1.972386588 Monday
21/03/2016  02:00   0.493230174 Monday
21/03/2016  03:00   2.149496514 Monday
21/03/2016  04:00   -0.367924528    Monday
21/03/2016  05:00   -0.056812802    Monday
21/03/2016  06:00   -0.056882821    Monday
21/03/2016  07:00   3.591736164 Monday
21/03/2016  08:00   -1.445430427    Monday
21/03/2016  09:00   1.592268753 Monday
21/03/2016  10:00   -1.746844705    Monday
21/03/2016  11:00   0.853445903 Monday
21/03/2016  12:00   -0.809900810    Monday
21/03/2016  13:00   0.036697248 Monday
21/03/2016  14:00   -1.091743119    Monday
21/03/2016  15:00   0.000000000 Monday
21/03/2016  16:00   2.357798165 Monday
21/03/2016  17:00   2.494451842 Monday
21/03/2016  18:00   0.806451613 Monday
21/03/2016  19:00   -1.846808511    Monday
21/03/2016  20:00   1.014568158 Monday
21/03/2016  21:00   0.583590800 Monday
21/03/2016  22:00   1.339590444 Monday
21/03/2016  23:00   -0.706832716    Monday
22/03/2016  00:00   -2.952872493    Tuesday
22/03/2016  01:00   0.697471665 Tuesday
22/03/2016  02:00   -0.296425458    Tuesday
22/03/2016  03:00   4.156738152 Tuesday
22/03/2016  04:00   -0.220675607    Tuesday
22/03/2016  05:00   0.110262935 Tuesday
22/03/2016  06:00   -0.025695931    Tuesday
22/03/2016  07:00   0.877796902 Tuesday
22/03/2016  08:00   -0.304594297    Tuesday
22/03/2016  09:00   0.644942295 Tuesday
22/03/2016  10:00   0.521797677 Tuesday
22/03/2016  11:00   0.000000000 Tuesday
22/03/2016  12:00   0.167448091 Tuesday
22/03/2016  13:00   -1.089689858    Tuesday
22/03/2016  14:00   0.508905852 Tuesday
22/03/2016  15:00   -5.001275836    Tuesday
22/03/2016  16:00   1.843565420 Tuesday
22/03/2016  17:00   -0.720372485    Tuesday
22/03/2016  18:00   0.639886242 Tuesday
22/03/2016  19:00   1.256859621 Tuesday
22/03/2016  20:00   -0.611353712    Tuesday
22/03/2016  21:00   0.122914838 Tuesday
22/03/2016  22:00   1.224632610 Tuesday
22/03/2016  23:00   -2.361038508    Tuesday
23/03/2016  00:00   0.757440741 Wednesday
23/03/2016  01:00   0.716941052 Wednesday
23/03/2016  02:00   1.004759387 Wednesday
23/03/2016  03:00   0.532332664 Wednesday
23/03/2016  04:00   2.246313964 Wednesday
23/03/2016  05:00   1.034775233 Wednesday
23/03/2016  06:00   -0.426813959    Wednesday
23/03/2016  07:00   -1.050861707    Wednesday
23/03/2016  08:00   0.160622200 Wednesday
23/03/2016  09:00   -0.016934801    Wednesday
23/03/2016  10:00   -0.594227504    Wednesday
23/03/2016  11:00   0.162393162 Wednesday
23/03/2016  12:00   0.509337861 Wednesday
23/03/2016  13:00   0.481418919 Wednesday
23/03/2016  14:00   -1.065078833    Wednesday
23/03/2016  15:00   0.771186441 Wednesday
23/03/2016  16:00   3.075630252 Wednesday
23/03/2016  17:00   -0.171204957    Wednesday
23/03/2016  18:00   -1.019991840    Wednesday
23/03/2016  19:00   0.476816837 Wednesday
23/03/2016  20:00   0.818665575 Wednesday
23/03/2016  21:00   0.390370852 Wednesday
23/03/2016  22:00   0.668405608 Wednesday
23/03/2016  23:00   0.574945340 Wednesday
24/03/2016  00:00   -3.086816720    Thursday
24/03/2016  01:00   -3.166666667    Thursday
24/03/2016  02:00   -0.223003688    Thursday
24/03/2016  03:00   0.837392122 Thursday
24/03/2016  04:00   0.000000000 Thursday
24/03/2016  05:00   -1.709401709    Thursday
24/03/2016  06:00   -0.786026201    Thursday
24/03/2016  07:00   0.070422535 Thursday
24/03/2016  08:00   -0.594977688    Thursday
24/03/2016  09:00   2.130094182 Thursday
24/03/2016  10:00   -1.924410541    Thursday
24/03/2016  11:00   -3.431984311    Thursday
24/03/2016  12:00   2.121771218 Thursday
24/03/2016  13:00   -1.261374899    Thursday
24/03/2016  14:00   1.012866137 Thursday
24/03/2016  15:00   2.333333333 Thursday
24/03/2016  16:00   -0.985915493    Thursday
24/03/2016  17:00   0.693529980 Thursday
24/03/2016  18:00   -0.915431561    Thursday
24/03/2016  19:00   -2.390613973    Thursday
24/03/2016  20:00   1.218631522 Thursday
24/03/2016  21:00   -1.218092253    Thursday
24/03/2016  22:00   1.074007220 Thursday
24/03/2016  23:00   0.566699649 Thursday
25/03/2016  00:00   0.071231413 Friday
25/03/2016  01:00   -1.539005838    Friday
```

Comment: Are you looking for average price movement per-hour per-day averaged across years?

Comment: yes, so im looking for each square to show the average price movement across all data for that particular hour and day

Comment: Please make your question reproducible so others can help

Comment: ok updated it with a snippet of data

Comment: Depending on the kind of financial data you're working with (say stock prices), if you try to find the average change in value over the course of several years that's going to average out to 0 because there is so much fluctuation in that data in any given day and definitely over the course of a year. It might be more effective to separate your data out by month and then generate a heatmap or maybe visualize it with a line graph. This would give you a ton of plots but would help you get a more meaningful understanding of the data.

Comment: Is there any way in R to calculate the average change for each particular hour for each weekday? I don't mind if its all close to zero, as I have other variables that I would like to plot and they may not be close to zero.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are currently overplotting many tiles on the same location. All you are seeing are the ones that happened to be plotted last. You are probably looking to use `stat_summary_2d`, which by default will calculate the mean for each square. E.g.:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Time, y = Weekday, z = Change)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1, stat = 'summary_2d') + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +  # or scale_x_time if formatted correctly 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name="Price change", option = "plasma")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are currently plotting data repeatedly. If you want the means, you would need to modify your code to something like this:

```
ggplot(data %>%group_by(Time, Weekday) %>% summarize_all(mean) %>%ungroup(), aes(x=Time, y=Weekday, fill = Change)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1) +     
  scale_x_time(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name="Price change", option = "plasma") + 
  theme_bw(base_family="Helvetica") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```